# WPF IDataErrorInfo validation after Value Conversion

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, converters

I've been searching around and it appears that `IDataErrorInfo` is currently the preferred method of input validation.

Combining `IDataErrorInfo` with a value converter have proved a bit tricky to me.

One question I asked my self, and in the end Google, was how to handle erroneous input in the Value Converter. A common practice appears to be to return the value unconverted in case of bad input. That makes a lot of sense since the view-model/model can validate the erroneous input and report back a more or less detailed description on what's wrong.

I'm having one problem with this approach however. Let's try the following scenario:

1. I have a textbox bound to a property of type `decimal` which the user is supposed to input a price into.
2. I have a value converter to transform the decimal point into a region specific decimal separator and round it to two decimals.
3. The user enters `aa12.4` into the textbox.

If my value converter returns `aa12.4` (because it's a erroneous value and not converted) it will be automatically converted to 0 when it is attached to the price property the text box is bound to. 0 (or 0.00) is a perfectly legal price which would validate to true.

As you might understand i don't want `aa12.4` to be valid and magically transformed to 0. I also loose all means to determine what's specifically wrong with the input and report that back to the user.

How do I handle this scenario? It's my understanding that the method handling the validation is called after the property is set. One idea I've read is to return `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` from the converter. That on other hand does not help the validator to determine what was wrong with the input, just that it wasn't convertible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using IDataErrorInfo, you could use ValidationRules, which allow you to inspect the value before it is converted and sent to the ViewModel. Or you could follow the more radical approach suggested by Josh Smith and others, and wrap all of your numeric / otherwise typed properties in String properties in the ViewModel, so that the ViewModel always knows about the unconverted / unconvertible value.

By the way, you don't need a converter in order to be able to use localized number formats, you can set ConverterCulture on the Bindings instead.